# How to select index of an element using .index() in query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to have the index of

using

```
this.config.curPos = $(this.config.el + ' li div').index($('.focus'));
```

I get always the wrong index.

The desired result is

id="input-username" = 0

id="input-password" = 1

I need to avoid using the ID selector using jquery.

Any idea how to solve this?

---

```
<ul>
  <span>
    Email:
  </span>
  <li>
    <div id="input-username" data-href="input-username" class="focusable focus">
      <div class="input" style="position:relative;">
        <span class="text" style="position: relative; left: 0px;">
        </span>
        <div class="cursor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <span>
    Password:
  </span>
  <li>
    <div id="input-password" data-href="input-password" class="focusable">
      <div class="input" style="position:relative;">
        <span class="text" style="position: relative; left: 0px;">
        </span>
        <div class="cursor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you also have control over the generation of the html?

Comment: what about $(this.config.el + ' li > div').index($('.focus'));?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it using the following CSS selector.

```
this.config.curPos = $(this.config.el + ' li div.focusable').index($('.focus'));
```

Comment: yes and $(this.config.el + ' li > div').index($('.focus')); will also work

Answer (score 0):

I cannot evaluate if your `this.config.el` is set correctly. For the code you provided, the following should work.

```
this.config.curPos = $('.focusable').index($('.focus'));
```

Here an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmHcN/)